# Update date input field with vuejs

Tags: html, date, vue.js

I'm trying to update a date input field via VueJS and `v-model`.

My HTML looks like this:

`<input type="date" name="due" id="due" placeholder="Due at" v-model="due">`

My data method in VueJS:

```
data () {
  return {
    due: '06/25/2017'
  }
},
```

When I open the page nothing happens. I just get this value in the input field: 'mm/dd/yyyy'. But when I change `type="date"` to `type="text"` it all works and I get the correct value of `06/25/2017`. **It does work in Firefox**, but not in Chrome.

Does anybody know what the problem might be?

Comment: Any luck on this issue ?

Comment: did you fix your problem... I am also having the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Change the splitter to `-` from `/` and the order to `YYYY-MM-DD`.

```
data () {
  return {
    due: '2017-06-25'
  }
},
```

https://forum.vuejs.org/t/v-model-with-html-input-type-date/11285/2